# php openssl encrypt stream on the fly

Tags: php, openssl, public-key-encryption, zipstream

I have a php script that downloads huge zip file that is compressed on the fly using zipstream ( http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/ ).

Is it possible to encrypt it using public key cryptography without storing the entire thing on servers disk or in memory?

As far as I can tell standard openssl_encrypt function requires entire data to be in the memory.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: I have looked into standard openssl extension for php as well as phpseclib, but both seem to require entire data to be in memory, passed as a string type argument as far as i can tell...

Comment: Use an [Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) like ECIES or DLIES.

Comment: The only stream encryption implemented seems to be mcrypt, and that only offers symmetric encryption. Why not simply secure the connection using the certificates instead of encrypting the files you send?

Comment: i am writing a wordpress plugin and can't assume all users to have https configured; symmetric encryption is no-go as the source of the plugin is open

Comment: Use [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) some on-the-fly symmetric encryption.

Comment: What is your use case? Communicating back to a central service, or delivering a zip file to a random user? Asymmetric crypto is not simply some tasty cream cheese that you simply smear on the bagel of unencrypted communication. The public/private key pair are only used for the exchange of keys used in subsequent *symmetrically-encrypted* data exchanges. The key exchanges themselves are not trivial to do securely either, see [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

Comment: the zip will be sent to a central server; i know that using tls would be ideal, but not possible, so next best thing is to implement it in php i guess... i was hoping that it has been done already (never roll your own crypto), but i guess i could make a hybrid encryption scheme on my own containing some on-the-fly symmetric encryption

Comment: Hah, searching for an OpenSSL stream solution and I come across my own comments. Anyhow, I've since found a [very well-done solution](https://packagist.org/packages/jsq/psr7-stream-encryption) implemented as stream wrappers that use OpenSSL calls to encrypt individual blocks and carry forward the updated IV data block-to-block. It is very clever and well-done.